# Empty name, caption and description of Facebook Post using API Request

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to set empty name, caption and description of link(post) when creating new Facebook post using `JavaScript API call`. Everything is working when i try to set something to those three parameters, but when i leave them black, the default parameters are set from the Link of the Website. If you try to change them in Facebook interface when manually posting them, you can leave them blank, so must be way for doing that using API call. Anyone have any ideas?

Here is the request:

```
FB.api('/' + page_id, {fields: 'access_token'}, function(resp) {
    if(resp.access_token) {
        FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed',
            'post',
            { 
            message: "", 
            access_token: resp.access_token,
            link: "www.example.com/post1",
            name: "",
            caption: "",
            description: "",
            scheduled_publish_time: "" 
            }
            ,function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: The argument “X is possible via the UI, so it must be possible via API as well” is simply wrong. _A lot_ of stuff that is possible via UI, is not possible via API.

Comment: We will simply wait because i didn't find anywhere(in official documentation) that is saying opposite.